# How "Reviewers" feature can be enabled for github.com repo?

Tags: github, review

Recently Github [introduced](https://github.com/blog/2291-introducing-review-requests) feature allowing request a review. It is supposed to look like this:
[image: Reviewers demo]

However when I push a pull request, the reviewers area is disabled (it's grey and gear icon is missing):

[image: Reviewers disabled]

**How can reviewers feature be enable for a Github repository?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set or request reviewers if you don't have write access to the project. You must be a maintainer to set it. If you are a maintainer you can use GitHub codeowners file to automaticially add reviewers when someone opens the PR: https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-code-owners